# Refresh tab contents even when returning to the application from a home button pressed

Tags: android, tabs

I want to refresh the tab with its latest content, even if the user is coming back to the activity from a previous home button click.

Answer (score 1):

You should override `onSaveInstanceState()` as explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state).

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you update the tab inside of `Activity.onResume()`.